# JavaScript in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, ide

Does anyone know if there are plans to implement JavaScript in MS Visual Studio, like they do all the other languages?

I am fairly new to coding in JavaScript, but I have come to realise how powerful a language it really is for creating RIA. The main problem is that when it comes to developing and debugging in the IDE, it’s nowhere near as slick as if I was writing in say C#.
Maybe this is just a limitation of visual studio and that there are much better environments in which to code JavaScript?

Above all the most important thing is debugging. Currently when I attach and step through the whole process is very clunky.

Comment: Clunky as in, steping through the code and looking up vars at runtime. Also the intellisense doesnt seem that great. I've been mainly using VS2008

Comment: @gonzohunter:  I'm still not sure whats clunky about it, VS lets you step-in, -over, -out, run to a line, set a breakpoint.  All very efficiently and simpy.  You can create watches on expressions, list the set of local values etc.  The debugging experience is not much different from that of C#.

Comment: Intellisense is much weaker but improved in SP1.  Since javascript is a dynamic language __and__ is executed in an alien runtime  its quite a tall order to get intellisense to work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS 2010 will have much better [support for Javascript](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikeormond/archive/2009/04/16/visual-studio-2010-enhancements-for-asp-net.aspx) and intellisense

> Further enhancements in VS2010 will
>   see vast performance improvements,
>   particularly with large script
>   libraries and the ability to recognise
>   dynamically generated objects and
>   other techniques used by many
>   Javascript frameworks that the
>   Intellisense engine in VS2008
>   struggles with. Significant efforts
>   have been made to improve the
>   Intellisense compatibility with 3rd
>   party libraries as well.

There's also [Spket IDE](http://spket.com/) exclusively for Javascript and XML development.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript works fine in Visual Studio 2008. It supports jQuery with full intellisense, and if I remember correctly, the debugger also supports JavaScript, at least in Web applications (though I'm not sure about that). I tend to do the debugging work in a browser though, because, well, that's where the action happens anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might find debugging Javascript easier in Firebug in firefox or even in IE8's built-in debugger.

I use VS to debug Javascript a lot, I can't say I find the experience clunky.  What do you find clunky about it?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has already been said, it is important to note that JavaScript has a very loose standard (to put it mildly). That being the case, "full" JavaScript InteliSense support will never be as robust as something like C# in Visual Studio or any other IDE. I expect (as has been mentioned) that support for JQuery, Prototype, and other JS libraries will be good but the core language will always be somewhat of a struggle, IntelliSense or no.